# Ruby on Rails pages are initially blank, but load properly on refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails

1. http://do.starterpad.com - the home page loads fine
2. Try clicking any of the footer links (Contact, Starters, Startups, etc) and notice that the page doesn't load
3. Click F5 or the reload button in your browser and notice that it loads fine now

This is quite strange.  Any ideas?

I should also note that it works fine on our developer's local machine, just not in the live site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is almost certainly an issue with [**Turbolinks**](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks)

The typical definition of a Turbolinks problem is that if it only happens when you click links (IE "not upon refresh"), it will be caused by Turboinks. I explain why in a minute, but first, let's look at what the issue is:

---

**Error**

I clicked the footer links, and the page did turn blank

Interestingly, it showed me that the `<body>` element of the page had been removed:

[image]

This is almost certainly a Turbolinks error now (as I'll explain below). So what's causing it?

There could be a number of causes - but one that stuck out was the fact you've included a `<script>` tag directly in your `<body>` element:

[image]

I believe this could likely be the problem. Either this, or having not ended your `</body>` tag correctly, will cause Turbolinks to mess up. The way to resolve this will be to make your [Javascript unobtrusive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript), allowing you to ensure you have all your tags in order

So here's how I'd fix it:

--

**Fix**

Firstly, put your Javascript into your [`asset pipeline`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html):

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//Pikwik
var pikwik = function() {
   var pkBaseURL = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://statsbox.info/" : "http://statsbox.info/");

    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + pkBaseURL + "piwik.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));

    try {
       var piwikTracker = Piwik.getTracker(pkBaseURL + "piwik.php", 25);
       piwikTracker.trackPageView();
       piwikTracker.enableLinkTracking();
    } catch( err ) {}
};

$(document).on("page:load ready", pikwik);
```

Apologies for mixing JQuery & JS - I felt it right to emphasize the fact you need to keep it to only loading at the start of a request. Looking at the PikWik code itself, it would appear that it will append a `script` tag to your page - meaning that if you want it to work with Turbolinks, that has to be done at the very start of the page load process

This will be in conjunction with you ensuring you have the `</body>` tag closed correctly

---

**Turbolinks**

To give you an idea as to why Turbolinks has a problem, you'll want to consider how it works:

> Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster.
>   Instead of letting the browser recompile the JavaScript and CSS
>   between each page change, it keeps the current page instance alive and
>   replaces only the body and the title in the head. Think CGI vs
>   persistent process.

This basically means that every time you load a page with Turbolinks, it will only load the `<body>` tag of the new page, leaving the `<head>` intact.

The problem with this is that if you have any dynamic scripting inside any of the `<body>` tags you wish to load, it's going to cause a conflict. This is what I think has happened here - which you can address with the above recommendation

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and turned out that happens due to a conflict between bootstrap CSS imports.

In short, I was importing Bootstrap 2 times in 2 different places
In application.html.slim

```
    link[href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous"]
```

And in application.scss

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

So I just remove the second import in application.scss and everything worked for me, pages were loading as they should.